# TFS error Could Not Find File [ProjectName].vsmdi

Tags: visual-studio-2012

This error when doing our first checkin is preventing us from adding the solution to TFS. Not sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error generally means that there is a pending change to a file that does not exist on disk.

So for whatever reason, your VS has told TFS that is is making a change to the file `[ProjectName].vsdmi`.  Subsequently, that file has been deleted from the disk.  So when VS goes to do the checkin, it tries to check in `[ProjectName].vsdmi` but it doesn't exist on the disk.  So you get the error.

Either

1. Undo the pending change and check in again
2. Find out whether you actually need that file (a vsdmi hile is related to the VS unit tests projects) and try to recover it.

Comment: being a "frist" check in of the project, how does it know about a pending change?

Comment: @GeorgeD. Well there will be an Add operation won't there.

Comment: I was just not sure how it knew it was pending change when it was the first time I was adding the project.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this a different way for a Class.cs file.  The file existed on disk, TFS/VS could not find it for some reason.

1. Copied the file out of VS (to Notepad)
2. Deleted the file in Visual Studio
3. Re-created the file in VS by right clicking add->new.
4. Pasted back in and saved.

This worked.